# ¿Cómo corregir un error al crear un histograma?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Necesito crear un histograma a partir de unos datos de posición y velocidad. EL código que utilizo es

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


g = np.genfromtxt('posandvel2.txt')
px=g[:,0]
py=g[:,2]
vx=g[:,1]
vy=g[:,3]
d=np.sqrt(px**2+py**2)
v=0.5*(vx**2+vy**2)

plt.hist(v, bins=30)
plt.title("Histograma de energía cínetica al momento 0")
plt.show()

plt.hist(d, bins=30)
plt.title("Histograma de distancia al momento 0")
plt.show()

#N-20   
f = np.genfromtxt('posandvel.txt')
px=f[:,0]
py=f[:,2]
vx=f[:,1]
vy=f[:,3]
d=np.sqrt(px**2+py**2)
v=0.5*(vx**2+vy**2)

plt.hist(v, bins=30)
plt.title("Histograma de energía cínetica al momento N-20")
plt.show()

plt.hist(d, bins=30)
plt.title("Histograma de distancia al momento N-20")
plt.show()
```

Y el error que se me presenta es el siguiente:

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> /home/wamba/Documentos/UdeC/11° Semestre/Software/ayuda3.py in <module>()
>      11 v=0.5*(vx**2+vy**2)
>      12 
> ---> 13 plt.hist(v, bins=30)
>  14 plt.title("Histograma de energía cínetica al momento 0")
>  15 plt.show()
>
> /home/wamba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, >     orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, hold, data, **kwargs)
>    3079                       histtype=histtype, align=align, >     orientation=orientation,
>    3080                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, >     label=label,
> -> 3081                       stacked=stacked, data=data, **kwargs)
>  3082     finally:
>  3083         ax._hold = washold
>
> /home/wamba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in >inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
> 1896                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer,      func.__name__),
> 1897                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
> -> 1898             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
> 1899         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
> 1900         if pre_doc is None:
>
> /home/wamba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in >hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
>   6193             # this will automatically overwrite bins,
>   6194             # so that each histogram uses the same bins
>   -> 6195             m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)
>    6196             m = m.astype(float)  # causes problems later if it's an >int
>    6197             if mlast is None:
>
> /home/wamba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in >histogram(a, bins, range, normed, weights, density)
>  665     if mn > mx:
>  666         raise ValueError(
> --> 667             'max must be larger than min in range parameter.')
>  668     if not np.all(np.isfinite([mn, mx])):
>  669         raise ValueError(
>
>  ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.
> ```

---

Los textos necesario estan en [pastebin1](https://pastebin.com/xzd1tziT)

y [pastebin2](https://pastebin.com/CyQeeFVM)

Comment: Para tratar de replicar tu error y así poder depurarlo, son necesarios los ficheros `posandvel2.txt` y `posandvel.txt`. Como probablemente sean demasiado largos para pegarlos en la pregunta ¿por qué no los subes a un pastebin o un gist y pones un enlace a ellos en la pregunta?

Comment: ya estan los pastebin

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en los datos de entrada y en la forma que los lees. Para futura referencia pongo aquí las tres primeras líneas de uno de los ficheros de entrada:

```
pos(x)          vel(x)              pos(y)                  vel(y)      
0.02071,        -0.2938,            -8.033,                  -0.6579
3.308,           0.04636,           -5.784,                  -0.3808
```

Como vemos tiene una línea inicial que no son datos, sino una especie de cabecera, y después los datos en sí llevan una coma tras cada uno de ellos (salvo el último de la línea).

Tal como los lees con `genfromtxt()`, sin más opciones, lo que espera numpy es que todo sean datos y separados por espacios o tabuladores. Ya que no es así, el resultado de la lectura contiene gran cantidad de `NaN` (datos que no ha podido interpretar como números). Por ejemplo:

```
>>> g = np.genfromtxt('posandvel2.txt')
>>> print(g)
[[      nan       nan       nan       nan]
 [      nan       nan       nan -0.6579  ]
 [      nan       nan       nan -0.3808  ]
 ....
```

Así que no es de extrañar que no pueda pintar los histogramas.

La solución consiste en pasarle parámetros a `getfromtxt()` que le informen de cuántas líneas componen la cabecera (para que no intente leerla) y cuál es el delimitador entre datos (basta decirle que es la coma, pues los espacios los ignorará al tratar de leerlos como *float*, que es el tipo de datos que supone por defecto). Es decir:

```
g = np.genfromtxt('posandvel2.txt', skip_header=1, delimiter=",")
```

Y análogamente para la lectura de `f`. Con ese cambio ya funciona. Como muestra, uno de los histogramas obtenidos:

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, esta todo ok

Comment: @Camila De nada. Para aprender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio, leete el breve [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).